Which admins get a chance to "review everything" after I accept a Slack channel invite? Channel admins or the organization I select?
I received a Slack channel invite. It says:

The organization you select is where you’ll find this channel in Slack. Admins will get a chance to review everything before you start collaborating.

Which admins get a chance to "review everything" after I accept a Slack channel invite? Channel admins or the organization I select?

The Slack organization I select. I realized that after Slack organization I selected turned out to disallow accepting Slack Connect invitations:

